# Add multibib citations in a thesis template

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, multibib

I'm writing my Ph.D. thesis using the default template provided by my university.

I need to integrate into this template a multi-bib file because one of my previous papers has a multi-bib citation (\cite and \citeA).

I tried multiple times without success. Specifically, I think there are conflicts between the packages "multibib" and "biblatex.", and I have issues creating the command "citeA" (I received, in any case, the error "citeA is undefined)

I think that the template structure is quite difficult to understand. However, I have attached the files that I touched on to change the settings.

main.tex:

```
\RequirePackage{silence} 

    \WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Usage of package `titlesec'}
    %\WarningFilter{scrreprt}{Activating an ugly workaround}
    \WarningFilter{titlesec}{Non standard sectioning command detected}
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,%1headlines,
                headinclude,footinclude,cleardoublepage=empty,abstract=on,
                BCOR=5mm,paper=b5,fontsize=11pt
                ]{scrreprt}

%********************************************************************
% Note: Make all your adjustments in here
%*******************************************************
\input{classicthesis-config}


%********************************************************************
% Bibliographies
%*******************************************************
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
\addbibresource[label=ownjournal]{ownjournal.bib}
\addbibresource[label=ownconference]{ownconference.bib}

\begin{document}


\frenchspacing
\raggedbottom
\selectlanguage{american} % american ngerman
%\renewcommand*{\bibname}{new name}
%\setbibpreamble{}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\pagestyle{plain}
%********************************************************************
% Frontmatter
%*******************************************************

\include{margin}
%\include{FrontBackmatter/DirtyTitlepage}
\include{FrontBackmatter/Titlepage}
%\include{FrontBackmatter/Titleback}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Dedication}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Acknowledgments}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Foreword}
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Abstract}

\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Contents}
%********************************************************************
% Mainmatter
%*******************************************************
\cleardoublepage
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%\setcounter{page}{90}
% use \cleardoublepage here to avoid problems with pdfbookmark
\cleardoublepage

\part[\textsc{Part I}: Introduction and Background]
    {{\LARGE Part I}\break\break{\normalsize Introduction and Background}}
\label{pt:pt1}
%\include{Chapters/part1/introduction}
%\include{Chapters/part1/background}
\cleardoublepage

\part[\textsc{Part II}: title]
    {{\LARGE Part II}\break\break{\normalsize title}}
\label{pt:pt2}
\part[\textsc{Part III}: title]
   {{\LARGE Part III}\break\break{\normalsize title}}
\label{pt:pt3}
\include{Chapters/part3/jss} %<-THIS CONTAINS THE MULTIBIB paper
%\include{multiToC} % <--- just debug stuff, ignore for your document


%*******************************************************
\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Publications}
\cleardoublepage


\include{FrontBackmatter/Bibliography}

%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Declaration}
%\cleardoublepage\include{FrontBackmatter/Colophon}
% ********************************************************************
% Game Over: Restore, Restart, or Quit?
%*******************************************************
\end{document}
% ********************************************************************
```

This is specifically the "incriminate" snippet:

```
{{\LARGE Part III}\break\break{\normalsize title}}
\label{pt:pt3}
\include{Chapters/part3/jss} %<-THIS CONTAINS THE MULTIBIB paper
```

MyConfig.tex (in this file, there libraries and other commands)

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\setstretch{1.15}

\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{.25}
\definecolor{gray50}{gray}{.5}
\definecolor{gray40}{gray}{.6}
\definecolor{gray30}{gray}{.7}
\definecolor{gray20}{gray}{.8}
\definecolor{gray10}{gray}{.9}
\definecolor{gray05}{gray}{.95}

\newcommand{\llangle}[1][]{\savebox{\@brx}{\(\m@th{#1\langle}\)}%
  \mathopen{\copy\@brx\mkern2mu\kern-0.9\wd\@brx\usebox{\@brx}}}
\newcommand{\rrangle}[1][]{\savebox{\@brx}{\(\m@th{#1\rangle}\)}%
  \mathclose{\copy\@brx\mkern2mu\kern-0.9\wd\@brx\usebox{\@brx}}}

\newcommand{\rb}[1]{
    %\vspace{0.3cm}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=gray!05,%gray background
        colframe=black,% black frame colour
        width=\columnwidth,% Use 5cm total width,
        arc=3mm, auto outer arc,
        boxrule=0.5pt,
        ]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\newcommand{\roundedbox}[2]{
    \rb{
        \noindent\usepackage{enumitem}
        \textit{\textbf{Finding {#1}}. #2}
    }
    \stepcounter{Finding}
}

\newcommand{\resquestion}[2]{%
    \vspace{5pt} %
    \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{blue!05}{%
        \parbox{0.97\linewidth}{% 
            \textbf{RQ$_{#1}$.} \emph{#2} %
        }%
    }%
    \vspace{5pt} %
}%


\mdfdefinestyle{stebox3}{%
linecolor=steBoxLine,linewidth=0pt,%
leftmargin=0cm,rightmargin=0cm,%
roundcorner=5pt,
topline=true,bottomline=true,rightline=false,leftline=false,%
backgroundcolor=gray05
}


\newcommand{\nb}[3]{
    \fbox{\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize\color{#1}#2}\textsf{\small$\blacktriangleright${\color{#1}\textit{#3}}$\blacktriangleleft$}
}
\newcommand\TODO[1]{\nb{teal}{TODO}{#1}}
\newcommand\NOTE[1]{\nb{blue}{NOTE}{#1}}
\newcommand\REVIEW[1]{\nb{red}{REVIEW}{#1}}
\newcommand\REMOVE[1]{\nb{gray20}{REMOVE}{#1}}
\newcommand\CITEME{\fbox{\bfseries\sffamily\scriptsize\color{red}CITEME}~\xspace}

\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}

\RequirePackage{fontawesome}
\newcommand{\rqanswer}[2]{%
    \medskip%
    \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{blue!05}{%
        \parbox{0.985\linewidth}{% 
            \textbf{\faHandORight\ Answer to RQ$_{#1}$.} #2%
        }%
    }%
    \medskip%
}%


\definecolor{boxblue}{HTML}{ADD8E6}
\definecolor{surveyblue}{HTML}{DAE8FC}
\newcommand{\implication}[2]{ %
    \vspace{5pt} %
    \noindent\fcolorbox{black}{boxblue}{%
        \parbox{0.98\linewidth}{% 
            \textbf{\faAngleRight\ Take Away Message #1.} #2 %
        }%
    }%
    \vspace{5pt} %
}%

\definecolor{headertable}{rgb}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0}

\newcommand{\examplebox}[2]
{   
    \smallskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=stebox3,frametitle={\textbf{#1}}]
    {\textit{#2}}
    \end{mdframed}
    \smallskip
}

\newcommand{\stesummarybox}[2]
{   
    \smallskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=stebox4,frametitle={\textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}]
    {#2}
    \end{mdframed}
}

\newcommand{\lessonbox}[1]
{   
    \smallskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=stebox3]
    {\faCheckSquare \hspace{0.05cm} \textit{#1}}
    \end{mdframed}
    \smallskip
}

\newcommand{\sterqbox}[2]
{   
    \medskip
    \begin{mdframed}[style=stebox1,frametitle={\textbf{#1}}]
    {\textit{#2}}
    \end{mdframed}
    \medskip
}

\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\markedsection}[2]{\section[#2]{#2%
\sectionmark{#1}}
\sectionmark{#1}}

\newcommand{\markedsubsection}[2]{\subsection[#2]{#2%
\subsectionmark{#1}}
\subsectionmark{#1}}


\newtcolorbox{reseachquery}{
    colback=gray!5,
    colframe=arsenic,
    boxrule=0.4mm,
    left=1.5mm,
    right=1.5mm,
    top=1.5mm,
    bottom=1.5mm,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    title={Search Query}
}
```

Bibliography.tex (In this file, there are the default settings to manage the bib file)

```
\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \phantomsection
  \manualmark
  \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vspace{\beforebibskip}}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\tocEntry{#1}}%
  \chapter*{#1}%
}%
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

I created a separate bib file (different from the one I use to quote with "cite") that contains the elements that I want to display with the custom citation, namely "appendix" in a specific subfolder (I have no idea if this is a problem).

The expected output should be something like this:

text text text\cite{key1} and \citeA{key}

References:

Key1 bla bla
.

.

.

Appendix:

Key bla bla

.

.

.

If there are problems, I can also attach the original template.

Comment: Welcome! Can you provide the code for a minimal document which we can compile to reproduce the problem? Fragments aren't generally very useful and it is hard for people to help without a (non-)working example. Try to reproduce the issue with a standard class (e.g. `article`) and as few packages as possible. `multibib` is incompatible with Biblatex. I don't know what it does as I've never used it, but producing multiple bibliographies is straightforward with Biblatex.